# CSV calulation script not saving the correct amount of columns

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, csv

@Stackoverflow

I have a script that adds three columns to the end of my csv based on matching 3 criteria.

I understand the problem, is that the code is re-reading line from rdr and that wrt is the modified line, after the initial loop I tried to iterate through wrt, but the code was unable to do that.

#### My code:

```
import csv
import datetime
import copy
from collections import defaultdict

with open(r"FullMergedData.csv") as i, open(r"FullMergedDataWSPSR.csv", "wb") as o:
    rdr = csv.reader(i, delimiter ="|")
    wrt = csv.writer(o, delimiter ="|")

    data, currdate = defaultdict(lambda:[0, 0, 0, 0]), None
    calclist = [6, 7, 19, 23, 25, 26, 35, 62, 64]

    for calc in calclist:
        for counter2, line in enumerate(rdr):
            if counter2 != 0:
                date, name = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[50], '%d/%m/%Y'), line[calc]

                if date != currdate or not currdate:
                    for v in data.itervalues():
                        v[:2] = v[2:]
                    currdate = date

                top,bottom = data[name][0:2]
                try:
                    quotient = float(top)/bottom
                except ZeroDivisionError:
                    quotient = 0
                wrt.writerow(line + data[name][:2]+ [quotient])

                data[name][3] += 1
                if line[38] == "1": data[name][2] += 1
```

If anyone can help with getting this code to work I would be very appreciative. Many thanks AEA

#### Code that produces traceback

```
import csv
import datetime
import copy
from collections import defaultdict

with open(r"FullMergedData.csv") as i, open(r"FullMergedDataWSPSR.csv", "wb") as o:
    rdr = csv.reader(i, delimiter ="|")
    wrt = csv.writer(o, delimiter ="|")

    data, currdate = defaultdict(lambda:[0, 0, 0, 0]), None
    calclist = [6, 7, 19, 23, 25, 26, 35, 62, 64]

    for counter, calc in enumerate(calclist):
        if counter == 0:
            for counter2, line in enumerate(rdr):
                if counter2 != 0:
                    date, name = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[50], '%d/%m/%Y'), line[calc]

                    if date != currdate or not currdate:
                        for v in data.itervalues():
                            v[:2] = v[2:]
                        currdate = date

                    top,bottom = data[name][0:2]
                    try:
                        quotient = float(top)/bottom
                    except ZeroDivisionError:
                        quotient = 0
                    wrt.writerow(line + data[name][:2]+ [quotient])

                    data[name][3] += 1
                    if line[38] == "1": data[name][2] += 1 

        else:
            for line in wrt:
                    date, name = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[50], '%d/%m/%Y'), line[calc]

                    if date != currdate or not currdate:
                        for v in data.itervalues():
                            v[:2] = v[2:]
                        currdate = date

                    top,bottom = data[name][0:2]
                    try:
                        quotient = float(top)/bottom
                    except ZeroDivisionError:
                        quotient = 0
                    wrt.writerow(line + data[name][:2]+ [quotient])

                    data[name][3] += 1
                    if line[38] == "1": data[name][2] += 1
```

#### Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\mergecalculator.py", line 35, in <module>
    for line in wrt:
TypeError: '_csv.writer' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?  Can you post a traceback?

Comment: @SunPowered added code of what I tried + traceback

Comment: Why are you iterating over a writer object?  What are you trying to do with `for line in wrt:`?

Comment: You can't iterate over a csv writer. For file-like objects, the iterator reads the file line by line.  you sure you don't want to iterate over `rdr`, i.e. `for line in rdr:`

Comment: @SunPowered The reason I posted the first bit of code without my attempt, was because I understood that it was wrong. The desired output should include 27 extra columns, instead it is only producing 3. Because it is not looking at the modified data.

Comment: Where in the code are you expecting your extra 27 columns to come from?  From what I see, you are taking your original line and adding `data[name][:2] + [quotient]` this should be an extra 3 columns

Comment: Indeed this is what occurs at the moment, but I want it to do it for each item in the calc list. My attempt to code this is flawed, I can see that. What I am hoping for is a suggestion of a way around the flaws contained in my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not 100% sure this is what you want, but try this logic.  You want to process each item in `calclist` to produce an extra 3 columns.  After all elements of `calclist` have been processed, add the resulting extra columns to the line and write to the csv file.

```
...
for counter2, line in enumerate(rdr):
    extra_cols = []
    for calc in calclist:
        # process data to get extra 3 columns
        extra_cols.extend(data[name][:2]+ [quotient])
    wrt.writerow(line + extra_cols)
```